# Collapsing overlapping time intervals using ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I read similar questions and it's possible to make it work by using window functions, however, since ClickHouse does not seem to support them I'm seeking for an alternative solution.

Given the time intervals like (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 8), (10, 15) I want to "merge" overlapping intervals into single ones. In my example, it would be:

(1, 8) and (10, 15).

Any pointers are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This task would have easily been resolved by [arrayReduce](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/array_functions/#arrayreduce-agg-func-arr1) If this function had been worked with arbitrary lambda. While this is not there, try to solve the problem by available means.

```sql
SELECT
    intervals,

    arraySort(x -> x, intervals) sortedIntervals,

    /* try to merge each interval with precede ones */
    arrayMap((x, index) -> index != 1
        ? (arrayReduce(
            'min', 
            arrayMap(
              i -> sortedIntervals[i + 1].1, 
              /* get indexes of intervals that can be merged with the current one (index is zero-based) */              
              arrayFilter(
                i -> x.1 <= sortedIntervals[i + 1].2 AND x.2 >= sortedIntervals[i + 1].1, 
                range(index)))),
          arrayReduce(
            'max', 
            arrayMap(
              i -> sortedIntervals[i + 1].2,  
              /* get indexes of intervals that can be merged with the current one (index is zero-based) */              
              arrayFilter(
                i -> x.1 <= sortedIntervals[i + 1].2 AND x.2 >= sortedIntervals[i + 1].1, 
                range(index)))))
        : x,
      sortedIntervals, 
      arrayEnumerate(sortedIntervals)) rawResult,

    /* filter out intervals nested to other ones */
    arrayFilter(
      (x, index) -> index == length(rawResult) OR x.1 != rawResult[index + 1].1,
      rawResult, 
      arrayEnumerate(rawResult)) result
FROM
(
    SELECT [(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 8), (10, 15)] intervals
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [(2, 4), (1, 3), (3, 6), (12, 14), (7, 7), (13, 16), (9, 9), (8, 9), (10, 15)]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [(20, 22), (18, 18), (16, 21), (1, 8), (2, 9), (3, 5), (10, 12), (11, 13), (14, 15)]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT []
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [(1, 11)]
)
FORMAT Vertical;

/*
Row 1:
──────
intervals:       [(2,4),(1,3),(3,6),(12,14),(7,7),(13,16),(9,9),(8,9),(10,15)]
sortedIntervals: [(1,3),(2,4),(3,6),(7,7),(8,9),(9,9),(10,15),(12,14),(13,16)]
rawResult:       [(1,3),(1,4),(1,6),(7,7),(8,9),(8,9),(10,15),(10,15),(10,16)]
result:          [(1,6),(7,7),(8,9),(10,16)]

Row 2:
──────
intervals:       [(1,5),(2,3),(3,8),(10,15)]
sortedIntervals: [(1,5),(2,3),(3,8),(10,15)]
rawResult:       [(1,5),(1,5),(1,8),(10,15)]
result:          [(1,8),(10,15)]

Row 3:
──────
intervals:       [(20,22),(18,18),(16,21),(1,8),(2,9),(3,5),(10,12),(11,13),(14,15)]
sortedIntervals: [(1,8),(2,9),(3,5),(10,12),(11,13),(14,15),(16,21),(18,18),(20,22)]
rawResult:       [(1,8),(1,9),(1,9),(10,12),(10,13),(14,15),(16,21),(16,21),(16,22)]
result:          [(1,9),(10,13),(14,15),(16,22)]

Row 4:
──────
intervals:       []
sortedIntervals: []
rawResult:       []
result:          []

Row 5:
──────
intervals:       [(1,11)]
sortedIntervals: [(1,11)]
rawResult:       [(1,11)]
result:          [(1,11)]
*/
```

Comment: Very good, but unfurtunately, too memory consumption. 2000 elements in intervals array lead to over 32Gb memory for this query work. SELECT arrayMap(x -> (x, x+1), range(2000)) intervals

Comment: @CHEM_Eugene thanks for your remark, it is really working slow, moreover, it works wrong ;( So give some time to try to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem and, unfortunately, the both answers here don't fit me.
The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347444/collapsing-overlapping-time-intervals-using-clickhouse/57447695#57447695) has a mistake. Just try it with the following example:

```
 [(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 8), (6, 9), (11, 15)]
```

It will return you

```
[(1, 8), (3, 9), (11, 15)]
```

The [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347444/collapsing-overlapping-time-intervals-using-clickhouse/63954651#63954651) is correct, but it needs to transform all intervals to lists of points. In my case I have a datetime intervals, so I have to create very big arrays with values of each second in the interval. It will be heavy.

That's why I tried to find solution, and I hope, I did it.

```
SELECT [ (1,5), (3, 7), (5, 10), (6,7), (7,8), (9, 12), (15, 20), (16, 22) ]  AS sortedIntervals,

   -- collect a new array with finishes of all intervals
    arrayMap(i -> i.2, sortedIntervals) as finishes,
    -- create an array with cumulative finishes (merge small internal intervals and increase finish)
    arrayMap( (i, y) -> arrayReduce('max', arraySlice(finishes, 1, y)), finishes, arrayEnumerate(finishes)) AS cumulative_finish,
    
    -- get sequence number of intervals, that will generate a new intervals (which will not be merged)
    arrayFilter ( i -> i > 0 ,
        arrayMap( (i, y) -> 
            -- there is no check for element existing, because array[0] will return 0
            -- if start of current interval is bigger then cumulative finish of previous one - it's a new interval
            ( i.1 > cumulative_finish[y-1] ) 
            ? y
            : 0, sortedIntervals, arrayEnumerate(sortedIntervals))
        ) AS new_interval_indexes,
    
    -- get result's intervals. 
    -- the first start - it's our initial start, finish - it's a value from cumulative finish of previous for new start interval
    arrayMap( (i, n ) -> 
        -- there is no checking on existing element, because array[<unexisting_element>] return 0, array[-1] return last element, that we want
        ( sortedIntervals[i].1, cumulative_finish[new_interval_indexes[n+1]-1] ) ,
        new_interval_indexes, arrayEnumerate(new_interval_indexes)
        ) as result
```

It will return

```
 [(1, 12), (15, 22)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT arraySplit((x, y) -> y, sortedDisArray, arrayMap(x -> if(x <= 1, 0, 1), arrayDifference(sortedDisArray))) AS z,
   arrayMap(el -> (arrayReduce('min', el), arrayReduce('max', el)), z) as result
FROM
(
  SELECT [(1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 8), (10, 15)] AS a,
        arrayMap(x -> x.2 -x.1 ,a) as durations,
        arrayMap((i, y) ->
            arrayMap(n -> n + a[y].1 ,
                range(toUInt64(durations[y]+1))) , durations, arrayEnumerate(a)) as disArray,
        arraySort(arrayDistinct(flatten(disArray))) as sortedDisArray
 )
```

Comment: it looks like it works wrong for *[(1, 8), (2, 9), (3, 5), (10, 12), (11, 13), (14, 15), (16, 21), (18, 18), (20, 21)]*

Answer (score 0):

one more solution to test:

```
select
    id,
    data.1      as period_group,
    min(data.2) as start,
    max(data.3) as end,
    end - start as diff
from
    (   select
            id,
            groupArray((start, end)) as arr,

            arraySort(
                y -> y.1,
                arrayFilter(
                    x ->
                    not(arrayExists(
                            a ->
                                a.1 <= x.1
                                and a.2 > x.2
                                or  a.1 < x.1
                                    and a.2 >= x.2,
                            arr)),
                    arr)) as arr_clear,

            arrayMap(
                x, y -> (x, y),
                arr_clear,
                arrayPushFront(
                    arrayPopBack(arr_clear),
                    arr_clear[1])) as arr_w_prev,

            arrayMap(
                x, y -> (y, x.1, x.2),
                arr_clear,
                arrayCumSum(
                    x -> x.1.1 > x.2.2,
                    arr_w_prev)) as arr_groups
        from
            values (
                'id String, start UInt8, end UInt8',

                ('a', 1, 10),
                ('a', 2, 8),
                ('a', 7, 15),
                ('a', 20, 25),

                ('b', 116, 130),
                ('b', 111, 114),
                ('b', 107, 109),
                ('b', 103, 105),
                ('b', 100, 120),

                ('c', 50, 60),
                ('c', 50, 70),

                ('d', 1, 5),
                ('d', 2, 3),
                ('d', 3, 8),
                ('d', 6, 9),
                ('d', 11, 15),

                ('e', 1, 5),
                ('e', 3, 7),
                ('e', 5, 10),
                ('e', 6, 7),
                ('e', 7, 8),
                ('e', 9, 12),
                ('e', 15, 20),
                ('e', 16, 22),

                ('f', 1, 8),
                ('f', 2, 9),
                ('f', 3, 5),
                ('f', 10, 12),
                ('f', 11, 13),
                ('f', 14, 15),
                ('f', 16, 21),
                ('f', 18, 18),
                ('f', 20, 21)
            )
        group by
            id) as t
    array join arr_groups as data
group by
    id,
    period_group
order by
    id,
    period_group;
```